# Creating Reusable Derived Data Sets in SQL Server Without CREATE TABLE Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am creating a large intermediate data set (millions of records, half hour runtime) that is used as parts of several other different queries. Ideally this would be stored as a materialized view or cached table but I don't have DDL access on the server.

Subqueries and CTE's are inefficent because they must be re-executed every time and can't be indexed. Local/global temporary tables work well but get lost when I disconnect.

Is there any way to create a more persistent temporary table (or equivalent) without DDL access?

Comment: can you Select Into copyoftable1 From, not over a temptable but a user table?

Comment: Have you tried creating a permanent user table in tempdb? If you can do this, yes there is a possibility you can lose it, but only in the event of a server restart or failover (which also kills #temp/##temp). You may also need to name it uniquely to account for concurrency.

Comment: @AaronBertrand there is no such thing as permanent temporary table

Comment: @maSTAShuFu That's not what I said. Also your offering of SELECT INTO requires the same DDL permission in the user database as CREATE TABLE.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Select Into was a trial and a question. Anything in the temptable will be flushed when the service restarts.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes, I mentioned that already. I assume this is something that needs to last for the duration of a batch, not a month. I mean, maybe you restart your servers a lot more than average...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I did try that but don't have access unfortunately: "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'tempdb'."

Comment: Well, you could ask for that. Or you could ask for your own isolated schema in the user database, so you could create the objects you need, without interfering with anything else. It should be easy to justify if you take your workload, and show them on your own system how much longer it takes to re-query the data so many times in the same batch.

Comment: Is there any way to create/access a local database or personal "scratch" database where I do have CREATE TABLE rights? With an open source server I would just create a local server where I have full access, but don't think that's an option with SQL server.

Comment: If you have sufficient permission then yes you can create another database on the same server... but I'm sure you don't. Clearly you need sufficient access to do what you need to do. The other option is of course to copy everything into a SQL server that you do have access to (like a local SQL Express install or a cloud SQL install). Which is the way that most shadow IT or half baked datawarehouses start.

Comment: further to that, there is certainly a way to create a database  on the server that you have higher access to (i.e. create table), but your admins would have to create it for you